# Where to find IntelliJ IDEA 64-bit executable in Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, ide, intellij

I want to run the 64bit IDE of IntelliJ IDEA but I couldn't find it in the `/bin/` directory. There's only the `idea.sh` file, no `idea64.sh`. How to run the 64bit program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the code of that shell script, particularly the lines around:

```
"$GREP" "64-Bit|x86_64|amd64" "$VERSION_LOG" > /dev/null
```

you will see that the script invokes the correct options according to your architecture.